# How can I generate Sequence Diagram from an executing java code

Tags: java, tomcat, sequence-diagram

I want to generate a sequence diagram from an executing java code, preferably on a App server.

Is there any kind of library which I can plug into Tomcat which will generate a Sequence Diagram of the code that has executed. This will let me know of all the class that has been touched during execution for a given action.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So there a set of modules which are pretty large and complex, and I need to understand how it works, now even before I go about debugging the code with no meta information. If I can get the sequence diagram for the code, it will make the job much easier

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714440/how-to-generate-sequence-diagrams-automatically-on-executing-junit

Answer (score 0):

You can attach profiler  to your tomcat jvm ( YourKit for example ), or something bundled with intellij  and it will provide you with this information -  not sure about real sequence diagramm.